# Groovy literal StringBuilder/StringBuffer

Tags: groovy, stringbuilder

Groovy supports a literal syntax for creating a StringBuilder/StringBuffer instead of the usual

```
def sb = new StringBuilder()
```

However, I can't seem to remember (or find on Google) the correct syntax.

Comment: `sb.append("text")` will concatenate your strings

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To get a StringBuffer in a single step, you could use

```
def sb = 'Hello'<<''
```

or even:

```
def sb = ''<<'' //4 single quotes, not double quotes
```

for an initially empty one.

I think (but I could be wrong) the reason for using a StringBuffer rather than a StringBuilder is to maintain compatibility with Java 1.4.

Comment: You would also use a `StringBuffer` in current Java versions if you need to concatenate strings thread-safely

Comment: Double quotes work fine, at least on modern groovy.

Answer (score 16):

To create a StringBuffer:

```
text = 'Hello '
```

To append:

```
text <<= 'World!'
```

[And this might help some more.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pg10255.html)

Comment: It seems that that text is converted from a String to a StringBuilder only when the '<<=' operator is used, correct?

Also, it's actually a StringBuffer not a StringBuilder

Comment: Yes, in fact my example might be overly simplistic. You do need to convert and reassign to StringBuffer, as such the `<<=` operator. Later you can just use `<<`. Also you are right about the `StringBuffer`, which is how they allowed in-place character replacement using the `[]` operator.

Answer (score 14):

I've just played with StringBuilder / StringBuffer in Groovy.

Some examples below:

```
// << operator example
def year = StringBuilder.newInstance()
year << 2
year << "0"
year << '1' << 4
assert year.toString() == "2014"

// You can use with operator
def month = StringBuilder.newInstance()
month.with {
    append "0"
    append '5'
}
assert month.toString() == "05"

// or just append String like in Java or you can leave parenthesis
def day = StringBuilder.newInstance()
day.append "1"
day.append('1')
assert day.toString() == '11'

// It's nice to know, that we can use StringBuilder directly in GString
def date = "$year-${month}-$day"
assert date == "2014-05-11"
```

**Note:**
Use StringBuilder when it is used only by one thread. StringBuilder provides an API compatible with StringBuffer. StringBuffer is synchronized, StringBuilder is not. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer-in-java) for more info.

Comment: There's nothing special about using StringBuilder directly in GString: "[any Groovy expression is valid](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation)". The [official documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation) shows `"The sum of 2 and 3 equals ${2 + 3}"` as an example.

Answer (score 2):

`String.leftShift()` [creates a StringBuffer](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#leftShift(java.lang.Object)).

AFAICS, you cannot create a String*Builder* via groovy syntax sugar. You can only create a StringBuilder explicitly. No operator overload on [String](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html) or [GString](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/GStringImpl.html) creates a StringBuilder that you can explicitly use. Java String concatenation [might create a StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1), but that instance wouldn't be usable in your code.

At the time of writing this answer:

- Another answer said to use `<<=`. `<<=` is merely a [java compound assignment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) that uses `<<`. In particular, there is no method for [overloading](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#Operator-Overloading) `<<=`.
- The accepted answer said to use `''<<'' //4 single quotes, not double quotes`. Double quotes work fine, at least on modern groovy.

The following code shows that we always get a StringBuffer, not a StringBuilder, for the result of various combinations of `<<` vs `<<=` and `""` vs `''`:

```
def ls = ''<<''
println ls.class
def lse = ''
lse <<=''
println lse.class

ls = ""<<''
println ls.class
lse = ""
lse <<=''
println lse.class

ls = ''<<""
println ls.class
lse = ''
lse <<=""
println lse.class

ls = ""<<""
println ls.class
lse = ""
lse <<=""
println lse.class
```

prints:

```
class java.lang.StringBuffer
class java.lang.StringBuffer
class java.lang.StringBuffer
class java.lang.StringBuffer
class java.lang.StringBuffer
class java.lang.StringBuffer
class java.lang.StringBuffer
class java.lang.StringBuffer
```