# what is the difference between StringBuilder and Stringbuffer?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [StringBuilder and StringBuffer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer-in-java)

what is the difference between StringBuilder and Stringbuffer?

Comment: StringBuilder is a bit faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some methods in StringBuffer are *synchronized* while StringBuilder is not *thread-safe* - and faster.

Rule of a thumb - use StringBuilder unless you have a use case, where a StringBuilder is used by more then one Thread (which would be a very rare case).

Answer (score 4):

Taken from the javadoc of StringBuffer:

> As of  release JDK 5, this class has
>   been supplemented with an equivalent 
>   class designed for use by a single
>   thread, {@link StringBuilder}.  The 
>   StringBuilder class should
>   generally be used in preference to 
>   this one, as it supports all of the
>   same operations but it is faster, as 
>   it performs no synchronization.

Basically StringBuffer can be used by multiple threads at the same time, since it's synchronized, but that also makes it a bit slower than StringBuilder which can only be used by one thread at a time.