# Adding html tags with Java based on regex, keeping data in matches

Tags: java, html, regex, parsing

Using java, I am writting a script to anchor link an html bibliography. That is going 
from: `[1,2]` 
to: `<a href="o100701.html#bib1">[1, 2]</a>`

I think I have found the right regex expression: `\[.*?\]`

What I am having trouble with is writting the code that will retain the values inside the expression while surounding it with the link tags.

This is the most of I can think of

```
while(myScanner.hasNext())
{
 line = myScanner.nextLine();
 myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(line);
 ...
 outputBufferedWritter.write(line+"\n");
}
```

The files aren't very large and there almost always less then 100 matches, so I don't care about performance.

Comment: Will the link URL be different depending on what's between the brackets?

Comment: Yes, so [1] should go to anchor 1, [29] to anchor 29. I am not quite sure what i'm going to do for [1,29] or [1-29], maybe just go to the first anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I think a better pattern to match the `[tag]` content is `[\[\]]*` instead of `.*?` (i.e. anything but opening and closing brackets).

For the replacement, if the URL varies depending on the `[tag]` content, then you need an explicit `Matcher.find()` loop combined with `appendReplacement/Tail`.

Here's an example that sets up a `Map<String,String>` of the URLs and a `Matcher.find()` loop for the replacement:

```
    Map<String,String> hrefs = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hrefs.put("[1,2]", "one-two");
    hrefs.put("[3,4]", "three-four");
    hrefs.put("[5,6]", "five-six");

    String text = "p [1,2] \nq [3,4] \nr [5,6] \ns";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\]").matcher(text);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        String section = m.group(0);
        String url = String.format("<a href='%s'>%s</a>",
            hrefs.get(section),
            section
        );
        m.appendReplacement(sb, url);
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

This prints:

```
p <a href='one-two'>[1,2]</a> 
q <a href='three-four'>[3,4]</a> 
r <a href='five-six'>[5,6]</a> 
s
```

Note that `appendReplacement/Tail` do not have `StringBuilder` overload, so `StringBuffer` must be used.

#### References

- [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

#### Related questions

- [Difference between `.*?` and `.*` for regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex/3075532#3075532)
- [StringBuilder and StringBuffer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer-in-java)