# in matcher.replace method,how to limit replace times?

Tags: java, regex

in `matcher.replace` method,only has:
`replaceFirst()` and `replaceAll()` two methods

i want limit replace 3 times,how to do?

example:

```
String content="aaaaaaaaaa";
```

i want to get result is: `"bbbaaaaaaa"`

my code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class T1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String content="aaaaaaaaaa";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a");

        Matcher m=pattern.matcher(content);
        if(m.find()){
            String result=m.replaceFirst("b");
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### On `appendReplacement/Tail`

You'd have to use `appendReplacement` and `appendTail` explicitly. Unfortunately you have to use `StringBuffer` to do this. Here's a snippet ([see also in ideone.com](http://ideone.com/5fq4i)):

```
    String content="aaaaaaaaaa";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(content);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    final int N = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      if (m.find()) {
         m.appendReplacement(sb, "b");
      } else {
         break;
      }
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb); // bbbaaaaaaa
```

#### See also

- [StringBuilder and StringBuffer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer-in-java)

  - `StringBuffer` is `synchronized` and therefore slower than `StringBuilder`
- [BugID 5066679: `Matcher` should make more use of `Appendable`](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5066679)

  - If granted, this request for enhancement would allow `Matcher` to append to any [`Appendable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html)

---

#### Another example: N times uppercase replacement

Here's another example that shows how `appendReplacement/Tail` can give you more control over replacement than `replaceFirst/replaceAll`:

```
// replaces up to N times with uppercase of matched text
static String replaceUppercase(int N, Matcher m) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(
                sb,
                Matcher.quoteReplacement(m.group().toUpperCase())
            );
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then we can have ([see also on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/6QN6y)):

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<[^>]*>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("<a> b c <ddd> e <ff> g <$$$> i <jjj>");

    System.out.println(replaceUppercase(4, m));
    // <A> b c <DDD> e <FF> g <$$$> i <jjj>
    //  1        2       3      4
```

The pattern `<[^>]*>` is just a simple example pattern that matches `"<tags like this>"`.

Note that [`Matcher.quoteReplacement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29) is necessary in this particular case, or else appending `"<$$$>"` as replacement would trigger `IllegalArgumentException` about an illegal group reference (because `$` unescaped in replacement string is a backreference [sigil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil)).

---

#### On `replaceFirst` and `replaceAll`

Attached is the `java.util.regex.Matcher` code for `replaceFirst` and `replaceAll` (version 1.64 06/04/07). Note that it's done using essentially the same `appendReplacement/Tail` logic:

```
// Excerpt from  @(#)Matcher.java   1.64 06/04/07

public String replaceFirst(String replacement) {
    if (replacement == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("replacement");
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    reset(); // !!!!
    if (find())
        appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
    appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}

public String replaceAll(String replacement) {
    reset(); // !!!!
    boolean result = find();
    if (result) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        do {
            appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
            result = find();
        } while (result);
        appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }
    return text.toString();
}
```

Note that the `Matcher` is [`reset()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#reset%28%29) prior to any `replaceFirst/All`. Thus, simply calling `replaceFirst` 3 times would always get you the same result ([see also on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/EnhGI)):

```
        String content="aaaaaaaaaa";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a");

        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(content);

        String result;

        result = m.replaceFirst("b"); // once!
        result = m.replaceFirst("b"); // twice!
        result = m.replaceFirst("b"); // one more for "good" measure!

        System.out.println(result);
        // baaaaaaaaa
        // i.e. THIS DOES NOT WORK!!!
```

#### See also

- [`java.util.regex.Matcher` source code, OpenJDK version](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#av_p04Hv9fs/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Matcher.java)

Comment: regarding the last one, if you do `result = m.replaceFirst("b").replaceFirst("b").replaceFirst("b");` or `result = m.replaceFirst("b"); result = result.replaceFirst("b"); result = result.replaceFirst("b");` it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

i think use [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replace-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-)

code

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.replace(content,"a","b",3);
```