# Need an efficient algorithm to implement String.replaceAll()

Tags: java, string

I found String.replaceAll() in Java with **regular expression** underlying. It works fine in short string.
But in case of long string, I need a more efficient algorithm instead of String.replaceAll().
Anyone could give advice?
Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to provide more details if you want a meaningful answer.

Comment: What language are you talking about ?

Comment: replaceAll() is quite tuned for the general case.  Sharing the specific string you are trying to search for might help come up with a better answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do incremental replacement, you can use an explicit `appendReplacement/Tail` loop to a `StringBuffer` (unfortunately no `StringBuilder` overloads as of yet).

Here's the idiom [from the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);
 Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT_SOURCE);

 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
 while (m.find()) {
     m.appendReplacement(sb, REPLACEMENT);
 }
 m.appendTail(sb);

 System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

This is pretty much how `replaceAll` is implemented.

The benefit of this method is that since you have full control over the replacement iteration, you don't have to store the entire output in memory at any given time as a potentially long `String`. You can incrementally build the output, flushing the `StringBuffer` content to the disk periodically. That is, using this method can be more *memory efficient* than using `replaceAll`.

(You can also do fancy replacements that is not supported by the current replacement syntax, e.g. `toUpperCase()` transformation).

Note that there is a request for enhancement for `Matcher` to be able to append to any [`Appendable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html). If granted, not only can you use `StringBuilder`, but you can also directly replace to e.g. a [`FileWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).

#### Related questions

- [in matcher.replace method,how to limit replace times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448330/in-matcher-replace-method-how-to-limit-replace-times/)

  - Has example of limited replacement and case transformation
- [`StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer-in-java)

#### See also

- [BugID 5066679: `Matcher` should make more use of `Appendable`](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5066679)

  - If granted, this request for enhancement would allow `Matcher` to append to any `Appendable`

Answer (score 0):

You could try `String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`. It still uses a pattern and a matcher but `target` is not a regular expression.

Comment: Precisely because this uses a `Pattern`/`Macher` underneath, it's wrong to think that this is a lot more efficient performance wise (though it should be acceptable).