# Use replaceAll certain amount of times

Tags: java

I'm using replaceAll to only list the numbers in a certain string and I was wondering if there was a way to limit the number of times it replaced. For example:

```
String s = "1qwerty2qwerty3";
s = s.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(s.trim().split(" ")));
```

This will filter out all the numbers in a string, giving the result: [1, 2, 3].
I want to know if there is a way to instead get the result [1, 2]. So, basically the method finds two numbers and stops. Thanks for any help!

Comment: use replace in a loop but replaceAll

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in matcher.replace method,how to limit replace times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448330/in-matcher-replace-method-how-to-limit-replace-times)

Comment: I think the best idea is to use the String method split​(String regex, int limit)  see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `replaceAll` is removing everything that isn't a digit, but you want to limit the numbers returned by the `split`! I would, instead, stream the result of the `split` - then you can `limit` that and `collect` it to a `List`. Like,

```
String s = "1qwerty2qwerty3";
s = s.replaceAll("\\D+", " "); // <-- equivalent to your current regex.
System.out.println(Stream.of(s.split("\\s+")).limit(2).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
[1, 2]
```

**And**, we can actually eliminate a step if we `split` on non-digits to begin with. Like,

```
System.out.println(Stream.of(s.split("\\D+")).limit(2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Instead of `Stream.of(s.split("\\D+"))`, use `Pattern.compile("\\D+").splitAsStream(s)`. That way, even the splitting operation is short-circuited after 2 splits.

Comment: *Caveat:* Will give initial empty string in result if input text doesn't start with number, and the empty string is counted as one of the two. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164848/5221149).

Comment: This caveat happened for me too, though I don't see it as too big of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than splitting away what you don't want, search for what you do want.

In Java 9+, this can be done easily with streams:

```
String s = "1qwerty2qwerty3";
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\d+")
                          .matcher(s)
                          .results()
                          .limit(2)
                          .map(MatchResult::group)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList()));

// or condensed:
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s).results()
    .limit(2).map(r->r.group()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

*<sup>Disclaimer: Idea of using `limit()` taken from [answer by Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164745/5221149).</sup>*

In Java 5+, you need a `find()` loop:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s); m.find(); ) {
    result.add(m.group());
    if (result.size() == 2)
        break;
}
System.out.println(result);
```

*Output from both*

```
[1, 2]
```

The advantage of these, over solution using `split()`, is that you won't get an empty string first, if input doesn't start with a digit.

*Example*

```
String s = "qwerty1qwerty2qwerty3qwerty";

// Using this answer
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\d+")
                          .matcher(s)
                          .results()
                          .limit(2)
                          .map(MatchResult::group)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList()));

// Using answer by Elliott Frisch
System.out.println(Stream.of(s.split("\\D+")).limit(2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));

// Alternate, applying comment to answer by Elliott Frisch
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\D+")
                          .splitAsStream(s)
                          .limit(2)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

*Output*

```
[1, 2]
[, 1]
[, 1]
```