# Should I use StringBuilder or StringBuffer for webapps?

Tags: java, thread-safety, stringbuilder, stringbuffer, java-6

I a writing a webapp in Java 1.6 and running it in tomcat. While I am not doing any explicit threading, I wonder about what is going on behind the scenes with Spring and Tomcat. Would I run into any issues using StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [StringBuilder and StringBuffer in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer-in-java)

Comment: @thinksteep This question is suppose to focus on what sort of threading happens behind the scenes in webapps and how that affects String building.

Comment: Probably not a duplicate.  This seems to be more of a question about threading in Tomcat than the StringBuilder/StringBuffer classes themselves.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using a local variable you can safely use `StringBuilder`. Each thread will get its own instance.

Comment: +1. And if you *are* sharing strings between threads (e.g. by using static fields), then you should probably be using `String` rather than either `StringBuilder` *or* `StringBuffer`.

Comment: To emphasize ruakh's point: passing immutable data between threads is the safe approach.

Answer (score 2):

Usually Java EE components are not thread-safe by default, so unless you synchronize the blocks of code where you use the `StringBuilder`, you'll experience race-conditions. So, you either have to take care of synchronization or use `StringBuffer`.

Of course, as already mentioned if the `StringBuilder` is a local variable, you don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Use StringBuilder since your builder is a local variable in doPost or doGet or else. It's true that multiple server threads use the same servlet instance but the fact that your builder is a local variable, there is no reason to worry ! If your builder was a member of your servlet class, sure you would get thread-safety problems. It's not your case i guess.

Answer (score 1):

The Java doc says regarding java.lang.StringBuffer:

> Whenever an operation occurs involving a source sequence (such as
>   appending or inserting from a source sequence) this class synchronizes
>   only on the string buffer performing the operation, not on the source.

This means your operations on your StringBuffer will be safe even if you are in multi-thread environment [like web app]. The safety of your StringBuffer instance as such is governed by the scope of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

if the code is in a Servlet (doGet/doPost) then multiple requests will cause the servlet instance to be multi-threaded. If the code is in a Spring bean it will depend on whether you configured the bean to be a singleton or prototype.

Comment: To be more precise, you should say: that the servlet instance might be shared by multiple threads serving different clients.

Comment: that is a better way of saying that. :)