# Write data to a String

Tags: java, string, object

This is probably very easy to solve, but I am stuck on this for a while now. I got a while loop which I use to write data. I want to write the data from the while loop to a String.

```
public void dumpPart(Part p) throws Exception {
    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
    if (!(is instanceof BufferedInputStream)) {
        is = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    }
    int c;
    System.out.println("Message: ");
    while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.write(c);  //I want to write this data to a String.

    }
    sendmail.VerstuurEmail(mpMessage, kenmerk);
}
```

Solved:

```
public void dumpPart(Part p) throws Exception {
    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
    if (!(is instanceof BufferedInputStream)) {
        is = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    }
    int c;
     final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    System.out.println("Message: ");
    while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
        sw.write(c);
    }
    mpMessage = sw.toString();;
    sendmail.VerstuurEmail(mpMessage, kenmerk);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to store this data as a String in an object?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I want to store the data in just a String, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can consider a `java.io.StringWriter` (as of JDK 1.4+) :

```
 System.out.println("Message: ");

 final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

 int c;
 while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
    sw.write(c);
 }

 String data = sw.toString();
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use [IOUtils.toString(inputStream)](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream%29) or something like it.

Comment: this is what I'd prefer if you don't need the while-loop for other reasons. Just convert it with: `String sPart = IOUtils.toString(is);`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the System.out call just initialize a StringBuffer before the loop and append to it:

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
  s.append((char) c);
}
```

Comment: c is an `int` so it may not compile.

Comment: I wouldn't use a StringBuffer if I can use a StringBuilder http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Comment: Right. Just that the StringBuffer is compatible with the pre-1.5 era.

Answer (score 1):

Its best to do it using the StringBuilder Object rather than StringBuffer ( [Difference between StringBuilder and StringBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer-in-java) )

```
public void dumpPart(Part p) throws Exception {
    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
    if (!(is instanceof BufferedInputStream)) {
        is = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    }
    int c;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    System.out.println("Message: ");
    while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append(c);

    }
    String result= sb.toString();
    sendmail.VerstuurEmail(mpMessage, kenmerk);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is:

```
        int c;
    System.out.println("Message: ");
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
        sw.write(c);
    }
    System.out.println(sw.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way :

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
byte[] b = new byte[4096];
for (int n; (n = is.read(b)) != -1;) {
  buffer.append(new String(b, 0, n));
}
String str = buffer.toString();
```