# StringBuilder ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, logging, stringbuilder

```
public class Log {

    private static StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();

    private static StringBuilder getLog() {

        return log;

    }


    public static void addToLog(String id, String name, String field, String operator, String value, String bValue) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String currentTime = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
        getLog().append(currentTime); // line 114

    }

}
```

Stack trace:

```
[java] Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 
[java]     at java.lang.String.getChars(String.java:863) 
[java]     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:416) 
[java]     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132) 
[java]     at com.retroficiency.system.Log.addToMatchingLog(Log.java:114)
```

This method usually works fine, but we encountered this random error, which I can't figure out why. There is a seperate method that flushes the log to a file and clears it with:

```
getLog().delete(0, getMatchingLog().length());
```

I do not suppose it is a Java bug? Is it getting too long? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

StringBuilder is not thread-safe.  You should be using StringBuffer in this case.

You can find more info in this other SO thread:

[Difference between StringBuilder and StringBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer-in-java)

Comment: I thought it was the other way around. Thanks. Accept in a minute.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason why this would happen, unless you access this method from different threads: `StringBuilder` is not thread safe. You could use a `StringBuffer`, which is thread safe or add some form of synchronization.

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

> Instances of StringBuilder are not safe for use by multiple threads. If such synchronization is required then it is recommended that StringBuffer be used.