# StringBuffer or StringBuilder in Servlet's doFilter method?

Tags: java

I'm implementing my custom filter:

```
public class MyFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter
```

Which should I use in this `doFilter` method - StringBuffer or StringBuilder?

I would like to use it in this way:

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
stringBuffer.append(MY_CODE_HERE);
response.sendRedirect(stringBuffer.toString());
```

or...

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append(MY_CODE_HERE);
response.sendRedirect(stringBuilder.toString());
```

I know that `StringBuffer` is thread safe, but would a `StringBuilder` be enough?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961254/stringbuffer-stringbuilder-when-to-use?lq=1

Comment: As the Javadoc suggests, you should always use StringBuilder if you can. Note: StringBuffer is only thread safe if you only perform one operation on it, it not thread safe for multiple operations making it pretty useless IMHO.

Comment: This doesn't feel like a duplicate at all - this refers to the implications of a `StringBuffer` in a filter, as opposed to what the difference between the two actually *is*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Local variables are thread-safe and variables declared inside the `doFilter()` method will be  thread safe. Use `StringBuilder` for your purpose, as you shouldn't unnecessarily incur the overhead of synchronization used in `StringBuffer`.

Moreover , The Servlet request and response objects are created afresh for every new request and response and so by their nature they are thread safe. The `doFilter()` method will be executed in separate threads for each request.

**Suggested Reading:**

1. [Why are local variables thread safe in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825847/why-are-local-variables-thread-safe-in-java).
2. [StringBuilder and StringBuffer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer-in-java)
3. [servlet-filters tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info)

Answer (score 3):

Since it will be a local variable and not shared by threads, StringBuilder can be used.

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder is a better choice as it is faster because of its non-synchronized nature. ServletFilter doFilter for each request run in its own thread so you don;t need a synchronized  datastructure. And if it is simply a local varibale then StringBuilder is the choice.

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuilder` is designed as **drop-in replacement** for `StringBuffer` without the `synchronization`.

Simply use `StringBuilder` unless you are really trying to share a buffer between threads. `StringBuilder` is the unsynchronized  relative of the original synchronized StringBuffer class.

In your case `StringBuilder` makes perfect sense. Even in other case, consider synchronizing method then using `StringBuffer`

Answer (score 0):

As long as it is in the method doFilter(), its `thread-safe` and `request scoped`. So, `StringBuilder` is the obvious choice.

Ofcourse, unless there are multiple threads spawning within that method which modify it concurrently :)