# Java String Buffer

Tags: java

How does a StringBuffer handle strings internally?
I tried running the below example and got the answer as "String are unequal".

From what I know is that the equals() returns true if both the strings have the same value. So what is happening in this case?

```
class StringBufferTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String newString = "HelloWorld";
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(newString);

    if (buffer.equals(newString)) {
        System.out.println("Strings are equal");
    } else {
        System.out.println("String are unequal");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: You are comparing a `StringBuffer` instance to a `String` instance.

Comment: Sure, the `equals()` method returns `true` if both the strings have the same value -- and the arguments are _both `String`s._

Comment: A `String` can never be `equal()` to a `StringBuffer` (or vice versa) since they are different classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're comparing an instance of `StringBuffer` with an instance of `String`, which won't give the desired results for being different types. Note that `StringBuffer` will use the plain [`Object#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) since it doesn't override it (noted by [`StringBuffer` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) against [`String#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) that indeed overrides it). You must compare the `String` content of the `buffer`, not the object reference of your `buffer` variable:

```
if (buffer.toString().equals(newString)) {
    //...
}
```

Also, from Java 5, it would be better using `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`. More info about this: [Difference between StringBuilder and StringBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/355089/1065197)

Answer (score 2):

`equals(` returns false when two objects being compared are *not* the same type. No matter the contained string, `StringBuffer` is a different type than `String` and the comparison will never be true.

`buffer.toString.equals(newString)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing:

```
if (buffer.equals(newString))
```

Which is actually comparing a StringBuffer object type to a String object type. That will obviously return false.

In order to get true returned from `equals` method you need to compare objects of same types.

[**As per official doc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> public boolean equals(Object obj)
>       Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.
>       The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references:
>
> It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
>       It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
>       It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.
>       It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.
>       For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

Answer (score 0):

The [`equals()` contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) implies that `x.equals(y)` returns true if and only if `x.getClass() == y.getClass()`. In other words, `x` and `y` must be instances of the same class. In this case, you are trying to compare a `StringBuffer` to a `String`. Comparing instances of two different classes will always be `false` for a well-behaved `equals()` method.

In order to do a meaningful comparison, you need to get the *contents* of the `StringBuffer`:

```
buffer.toString().equals(newString)
```

Answer (score 0):

can not **equals** a `String` Object with a `StringBuffer` Object, use:

buffer.toString().equals(newString)

and better use `StringBuilder`, because `StringBuffer` not TheredSafe