# Best way to modify an existing string? StringBuilder or convert to char array and back to string?

Tags: java, string

I'm learning Java and am wondering what's the best way to modify strings here (both for performance and to learn the preferred method in Java). Assume you're looping through a string and checking each character/performing some action on that index in the string.

Do I use the `StringBuilder` class, or convert the string into a char array, make my modifications, and then convert the char array back to a string?

Example for `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder(oldString);
for (int i = 0; i < oldString.length() ; i++) {
    newString.setCharAt(i, 'X');    
}
```

Example for char array conversion:

```
char[] newStringArray = oldString.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < oldString.length() ; i++) {
    myNameChars[i] = 'X';    
}    
myString = String.valueOf(newStringArray);
```

What are the pros/cons to each different way?

I take it that `StringBuilder` is going to be more efficient since the converting to a char array makes copies of the array each time you update an index.

Comment: Please use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `StringBuilder` uses a `char` array internally (similar to yours), so I'd recommend letting the ready-made class do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: There are almost never universal answers for questions like this.  The best answer is ... "it depends on what you're doing."  Strings are immutable and so they are always threadsafe.  If you are doing a string manipulation in a concurrent environment on shared state variables, then it may be greatly to your advantage to use String.  For thread confined mutable state, as others have pointed out, StringBuilder will get you superior performance.  For shared mutable state, StringBuilder will need to be guarded by a lock before a thread can modify it and this can cause performance bottlenecks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I say do whatever is most readable/maintainable until you you know that String "modification" is slowing you down.  To me, this is the most readable:

```
Sting s = "foo";
s += "bar";
s += "baz";
```

If that's too slow, I'd use a `StringBuilder`.  You may want to [compare this to `StringBuffer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/355092/61624).  If performance matters and synchronization does not, `StringBuilder` should be faster.  If sychronization is needed, then you should use `StringBuffer`.

Also it's important to know that these strings are not being modified.  In java, `String`s are immutable.

---

This is all context specific.  If you optimize this code and it doesn't make a noticeable difference (and this is usually the case),  then you just thought longer than you had to and you probably made your code more difficult to understand.  Optimize when you *need* to, not because you can.  And before you do that, make sure the code you're optimizing is the cause of your performance issue.

Comment: Fun fact: every Java compiler I have seen implements the string concatenation operator using a `StringBuilder` anyway, so in many cases the resulting bytecode should be (more or less) identical.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I always thought it *should* do that.  Has it always been the case?  Why does `StringBuilder` need to exist if it's used regardless?

Comment: @mikestrobel I just massively improved parsing performance in one of my applications switching to stringbuilder in certain situations.

Comment: There is no JVM-level instruction that represents a string concatenation.  To my knowledge, it has always been emitted as a series of `StringBuilder.append()` calls (or, prior to Java 5, `StringBuffer.append()` calls).  I would imagine the results are only "optimal" for concatenations which occur within the same expression, e.g., "a" + 1 + "c".  Breaking the operations into separate statements may produce less than optimal results.  Also, different compilers may optimize these operations more aggressively than others.

Comment: In my case Stringbuilder avoided the creation of millin s of (lengthy) strings and their cocatenation.  Admittedly I was parsing thousands of csv files so its situation dependant but I cut running time by 2/3rds

Comment: Yeah, any sort of string building where you are performing disjoint modifications should benefit from using a single StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the pros/cons to each different way. I take it that StringBuilder is going to be more efficient since the convering to a char array makes copies of the array each time you update an index.

As written, the code in your second example will create just two arrays: one when you call `toCharArray()`, and another when you call `String.valueOf()` (`String` stores data in a char[] array).  The element manipulations you are performing should not trigger any object allocations.  There are no copies being made of the array when you read or write an element.

If you are going to be doing any sort of `String` manipulation, the recommended practice is to use a `StringBuilder`.  If you are writing very performance-sensitive code, and your transformation does not alter the length of the string, then it might be worthwhile to manipulate the array directly.  But since you are learning Java as a new language, I am going to guess that you are not working in high frequency trading or any other environment where latency is critical.  Therefore, you are probably better off using a `StringBuilder`.

If you are performing any transformations that might yield a string of a different length than the original, you should almost certainly use a `StringBuilder`; it will resize its internal buffer as necessary.

On a related note, if you are doing simple string concatenation (e.g, `s = "a" + someObject + "c"`), the compiler will actually transform those operations into a chain of `StringBuilder.append()` calls, so you are free to use whichever you find more aesthetically pleasing.  I personally prefer the `+` operator.  However, if you are building up a string across multiple statements, you should create a single `StringBuilder`.

For example:

```
public String toString() {
    return "{field1 =" + this.field1 + 
           ",  field2 =" + this.field2 + 
           ...
           ",  field50 =" + this.field50 + "}";
}
```

Here, we have a single, long expression involving many concatenations.  You don't need to worry about hand-optimizing this, because the compiler will use a single `StringBuilder` and just call `append()` on it repeatedly.

```
String s = ...;
if (someCondition) {
    s += someValue;
}
s += additionalValue;
return s;
```

Here, you'll end up with two `StringBuilders` being created under the covers, but unless this is an extremely hot code path in a latency-critical application, it's really not worth fretting about.  Given similar code, but with many more separate concatenations, it might be worth optimizing.  Same goes if you know the strings might be *very large*.  But don't just guess--measure!  Demonstrate that there's a performance problem before you try to fix it.  *(Note: this is just a general rule for "micro optimizations"; there's rarely a downside to explicitly using a `StringBuilder`.  But don't assume it will make a measurable difference: if you're concerned about it, you should actually **measure**.)*

```
String s = "";
for (final Object item : items) {
    s += item + "\n";
}
```

Here, we're performing a separate concatenation operation on each loop iteration, which means a new `StringBuilder` will be allocated on each pass.  In this case, it's probably worth using a single `StringBuilder` since you may not know how large the collection will be.  I would consider this an exception to the "prove there's a performance problem before optimizing rule": if the operation has the potential to explode in complexity based on input, err on the side of caution.

Comment: Most JVMs will do the optimization of changing concatenation to a StringBuilder and then back to a String.  The important exception is for concatenations that occur within loops.  In that case, it is usually important to explicitly do the string manipulations with StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

Which option will perform the best is not an easy question.

I did a [benchmark](https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/runs/11b2bb8c-2e51-484f-9d20-2681999663a9#r%3ascenario.benchmarkSpec.methodName) using [Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/):

```
                RUNTIME (NS)
array           88
builder         126
builderTillEnd  76
concat          3435
```

### Benchmarked methods:

```
public static String array(String input)
{
    char[] result = input.toCharArray(); // COPYING
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        result[i] = 'X';
    }
    return String.valueOf(result); // COPYING
}

public static String builder(String input)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(input); // COPYING
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        result.setCharAt(i, 'X');
    }
    return result.toString(); // COPYING
}

public static StringBuilder builderTillEnd(String input)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(input); // COPYING
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        result.setCharAt(i, 'X');
    }
    return result;
}

public static String concat(String input)
{
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) 
    {
        result += 'X'; // terrible COPYING, COPYING, COPYING... same as:
                       // result = new StringBuilder(result).append('X').toString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

### Remarks

1. If we want to modify a String, we have to do at least 1 copy of that input String, because Strings in Java are immutable.
2. [`java.lang.StringBuilder`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuilder.java) extends [`java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.setCharAt%28int,char%29). `StringBuilder.setCharAt()` is inherited from `AbstractStringBuilder` and looks like this:

   ```
   public void setCharAt(int index, char ch) {
       if ((index < 0) || (index >= count))
           throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
       value[index] = ch;
   }
   ```

   `AbstractStringBuilder` internally uses the simplest char array: `char value[]`. So, `result[i] = 'X'` is very similar to `result.setCharAt(i, 'X')`, however the second will call a polymorphic method (which probably gets inlined by JVM) and check bounds in `if`, so it will be a bit slower.

### Conclusions

1. If you can operate on `StringBuilder` until the end (you don't need String back) - do it. It's the preferred way and also the fastest. Simply the best.
2. If you want String in the end **and this is the bottleneck** of your program, then you might consider using char array. In benchmark char array was ~25% faster than `StringBuilder`. Be sure to properly measure execution time of your program before and after optimization, because there is no guarantee about this 25%.
3. Never concatenate Strings in the loop with `+` or `+=`, unless you really know what you do. Usally it's better to use explicit `StringBuilder` and `append()`.

Comment: result.toString() alone is about 50 NS (whole rest being 75NS) :O shocking fact !

Comment: if you could add stringA = aStr + bStr timings then it would be more useful comparison of beginners like me who know its expensive but cant measure it

Comment: @SrinathGanesh No problem, added. It's very slow :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to use `StringBuilder` class where original string is modified.

For String manipulation, I like [StringUtil](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class. You'll need to get Apache commons dependency to use it