# getting entries on 1 at a time

Tags: android, sqlite

what i'm trying to do is get entries, one-by-one, here's the code.

```
Teams.Java
public String getData(String key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { Key };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        String result = "";
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(Key);
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + "," + c.getString(iName);

        }
        return result;
    }
```

the activity

```
MainActivity.java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvINames);
        Teams stat = new Teams(this);
        stat.open();
        String Names = stat.getName("KEY_TEAMS");
        stat.close();
        t1.setText(Names);
```

if the logcat is needed, just tell me.

Comment: Just get all the values in that function. Return the ArrayList<String> or String[] and iterate to use that data. What's issue in that?

Comment: i should have done that but im using datatable for each field.i mean, its really 3 different fields that im getting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the 'Key' on the lines:

```
String[] columns = new String[] { Key };
```

and

```
int iName = c.getColumnIndex(Key);
```

uses a capital 'K' where as the parameter in the method-header is named with a normal 'k':

```
public String getData(String key) {
```

Do you have a field defined with the name 'Key' inside Teams.java?
I can imagine that this does not lead to the expected behaviour of your code, since the parameter is not even used.

Another thing I would definitely change is using a StringBuilder (or StringBuffer if it has to be thread-safe) for concatenating the string inside the getData()-method.

And for iterating over the cursor I would just use:

```
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    ...
}
```

---

Another inconsistency exists on following line:

```
String Names = stat.getName("KEY_TEAMS");
```

you are calling another method than the shown getData(String key)-method.

---

If I may rewrite your method I would suggest something like this:

```
//Teams.Java
public String getData(String key) {

    String[] columns = new String[] { key };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    final int iName = c.getColumnIndex(key);

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        result.append(c.getString(iName));
        result.append(",");
    }

    return result.toString();
}

AND

//MainActivity.java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Teams stat = new Teams(this);

    try {
        stat.open();

        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvINames);
        t1.setText(stat.getData("KEY_TEAMS"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "some meaningful error message 42!", e);
    } finally {
        stat.close();
    }

}
```

In general it is a very good idea to wrap all access to cursors into a try-catch-finally block for making sure, that it is closed in any case!

Comment: as for the public String getData(String key){..it was Key, i just misplelled. if i have a filed defined with the name key, i don't know if thats needed anymore since i pass the variable from MainActivity.java. and can you explain more about that StringBuffer thing?

Comment: you can read more about StringBuffer/StringBuilder here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer

Comment: For making you code clean and easier to understand what is going on, I would remove any field inside Teams.java with the name 'Key' or 'key'. If you need them as a fallback, when the parameter from the methods are not usable, you can still have a field named 'mKey' (m stands for member, so you know immediately where it comes from) or even use a constant

    private static final String DEFAULT_KEY;