# What actual cause the StringBuilder fails in multi threading environment

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, stringbuilder

`StringBuffer` is synchronized but `StringBuilder` is not ! This has been discussed deeply at [Difference between StringBuilder and StringBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer).

There is an example code there (Answered by @NicolasZozol), which address two issues:

- compares the performance of these `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder`
- shows the `StringBuilder` could fail in a multithread environment.

My question is about **second part**, exactly what makes it to go wrong?!
When you run the code some times, the stack trace is displayed as below:

```
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-2" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.String.getChars(String.java:826)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:416)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:179)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:72)
    at test.SampleTest.AppendableRunnable.run(SampleTest.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

When I trace down the code I find that the class which actually throws the exception is: `String.class` at `getChars` method which calls `System.arraycopy(value, srcBegin, dst, dstBegin, srcEnd - srcBegin);` According to `System.arraycopy` javadoc:

> Copies an array from the specified source array, beginning at the
>   specified position, to the specified position of the destination
>   array. A subsequence of array components are copied from the source
>   array referenced by src to the destination array referenced by dest.
>   The number of components copied is equal to the length argument.
>   ....
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if copying would cause access of data
>   outside array bounds.

For simplicity I have exactly paste the code here:

```
public class StringsPerf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ThreadPoolExecutor executorService = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        //With Buffer
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
            executorService.execute(new AppendableRunnable(buffer));
        }
        shutdownAndAwaitTermination(executorService);
        System.out.println(" Thread Buffer : "+ AppendableRunnable.time);

        //With Builder
        AppendableRunnable.time = 0;
        executorService = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
            executorService.execute(new AppendableRunnable(builder));
        }
        shutdownAndAwaitTermination(executorService);
        System.out.println(" Thread Builder: "+ AppendableRunnable.time);

    }

   static void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
        pool.shutdown(); // code reduced from Official Javadoc for Executors
        try {
            if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                pool.shutdownNow();
                if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                    System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}

class AppendableRunnable<T extends Appendable> implements Runnable {

    static long time = 0;
    T appendable;
    public AppendableRunnable(T appendable){
        this.appendable = appendable;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int j = 0 ; j < 10000 ; j++){
            try {
                appendable.append("some string");
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
        time+=(System.currentTimeMillis() - t0);
    }
}
```

Can you please describe in more details (or with a sample) to show how multithread cause the `System.arraycopy` fails, ?! Or how the threads make `invalid data` passed to `System.arraycopy` ?!

Comment: StringBuilder is same as the StringBuffer , that is it stores the object in heap and it can also be modified . The main difference between the StringBuffer and StringBuilder is that StringBuilder is not thread safe. StringBuilder is fast as it is not thread safe .

Comment: @therealprashant of course!! I have asked for details,  _why_ it goes wrong?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I understand it. You should go one step back and look at where `getChars` is called from in the `AbstractStringBuilder` `append` method:

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(String str) {
    if (str == null) str = "null";
    int len = str.length();
    ensureCapacityInternal(count + len);
    str.getChars(0, len, value, count);
    count += len;
    return this;
}
```

The `ensureCapacity` method will check that the attribute `value` is long enough to store the appended value and if not then it will resize accordingly.

Lets say 2 threads invoke this method on the same instance. Keep in mind that `value` and `count` is accessed by both threads. In this contrived scenario, say `value` is an array of size 5 and there are 2 characters in the array so `count=2` (if you look at the `length` method you'll see that it returns `count`).

Thread 1 invokes `append("ABC")` which will call `ensureCapacityInternal` and `value` is big enough so it is not resized (requires size 5). Thread 1 pauses.

Thread 2 invokes `append("DEF")` which will call `ensureCapacityInternal` and `value` is big enough so it is not resized either (also requires size 5). Thread 2 pauses.

Thread 1 continues and calls `str.getChars` with no problems. It then calls `count += len`. Thread 1 pauses. Note that `value` now contains 5 characters and is length 5.

Thread 2 now continues and calls `str.getChars`. Remember that it uses the same `value` and same `count` as Thread 1. But now, `count` has increased and could potentially be greater than the size of `value` i.e. the destination index to copy is greater than the length of the array which causes `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when invoking the `System.arraycopy` within `str.getChars`. In our contrived scenario, `count=5` and the size of `value` is 5 so when `System.arraycopy` is called, it cannot copy to the 6th position of an array that's length 5.

Answer (score 2):

If you compare `append` method in both the classes i.e. `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer`. You can find [StringBuilder.append()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuilder.java#StringBuilder.append%28java.lang.String%29) is **not synchronized** where as [StringBuffer.append()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuffer.java#StringBuffer.append%28java.lang.String%29) is **synchronized**.

```
// StringBuffer.append
public synchronized StringBuffer append(String str) {
    super.append(str);
    return this;
}

// StringBuilder.append
public StringBuilder append(String str) {
    super.append(str);
    return this;
}
```

So when you try to append `"some string"` using multiple threads.

In case of **StringBuilder**, 
`ensureCapacityInternal()` is called from different threads at the same time. This result in change of size based on previous value in both the call, and after that both the threads are appending `"some string"` causing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**Eg:** 
String value is "some stringsome string". Now 2 threads want to append "some string". So both will call `ensureCapacityInternal()` method and which will result in increase in length if enough space is not available, But if there are 11 places remaining then it will not increment the size. Now two threads have called `System.arraycopy` with "some string" at the same time. And then both threads try to append "some string". So actual length increase should be 22, but char[] has 11 empty places inside it, resulting in ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

In case of **StringBuffer**, append method is already synchronized, so this scenario won't arise.