# Java String Buffer - how to delete

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

I need to create a method which takes in a String and produces a new word which does not include vowels and replaces each consonant with its position in the original word. The word I am using is `"program"` so I should get back `"12o457"`.

Below is my code - I am getting an out of bounds when I try to use the `deleteCharAt` but I can use append here fine.

```
public class Methods {

    public String getWord(String word){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();


        for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++)
        {
            if(word.charAt(i) =='a' ||
                word.charAt(i) == 'e' ||
                word.charAt(i) == 'i')
                {
                sb.deleteCharAt(i);
                }
        else if(word.charAt(i)=='o' || word.charAt(i)=='u')
            {
            sb.append(word.charAt(i));
            }
        else{sb.append((i));}
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't contain vowels but you keep the `o` so, I don't understand it

Comment: Shouldn't the result be `"12o4567"`? (note the 6).

Comment: @Tunaki actually it should be `"01346"` (as far as I can see)

Comment: You're trying to delete letters that you haven't added yet. Why? Just don't append them if you don't want them.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer, it was replaced by StringBuilder more than 10 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to delete a char you never had on your StringBuilder, you just need to change your method as follows:

```
public String getWord(String word) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (word.charAt(i) == 'o' || word.charAt(i) == 'u') {
            sb.append(word.charAt(i));
        } else if (word.charAt(i) != 'a' && word.charAt(i) != 'e' && word.charAt(i) != 'i') {
            sb.append((i + 1));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This way you only add the letters you want for example `o` and `u` and skip `a`, `e`, `i` vowels and all consonants. Also, indexes in Java start from `0` so, to get your desired ouput, you needed to append `i + 1` instead of just `i`.

After running the above code I get:

```
12o457
```

as expected. However you should rephrase your question because you don't want any vowel and you're adding `o` and `u` which are vowels. And you want the original position, so it's not `i + 1` but `i` and it would give you:

```
01o346
```

However with a larger word this could give something like the following:

```
Input: programprogram
Output: 12o45789o111214
```

As you can see it becomes messy. Hopefully you won't use a word with a length > 10 chars.

**Edit**

Also I hadn't noticed this but as @PeterLawrey said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518431/java-string-buffer-how-to-delete/34518685#comment56778714_34518431) above, don't use [`String Buffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) instead use a [`String Builder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). For more information about this, see [StringBuilder vs StringBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, works perfectly, sorry about the phrasing of the question I think I was looking at it for so long I lost the plot a bit! So simple now I see it, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't to need use method `deleteCharAt(i)` for StringBuilder, because it is empty by default and you add only characters you want and also in `Strings` indexes starts from 0, so you need append (i+1) for consonant's position

```
public static String getWord(String word) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {

        if (word.charAt(i) == 'o' || word.charAt(i) == 'u') {
            sb.append(word.charAt(i));
        } else if (!(word.charAt(i) == 'a' ||
                word.charAt(i) == 'e' ||
                word.charAt(i) == 'i')) {
            sb.append((i + 1));
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String string="how are you?";       
    string.replaceall("[a|e|o|i|u]","*");

    while(string.contains("*")){
    string.replaceFirst("*",string.indexOf("*")+1);
    }
```

this will work :)