# Convert the string into stringBuilder in java

Tags: java

I have one method which returns the string but I want the data inside the method in StringBuilder and convert it into string then how can I do it?

```
  public String[][] getDataOfJD(List<JobDescriptionField> jdFields) {
  int i = 0;
  String [][] data = new String[jdFields.size()][];
  for(JobDescriptionField field : jdFields) {
      if (i > 0){
          String messages = "";
          for (String message : field.getMessages()){
             messages += message;
          }
     data [i] = new String[]{field.getTitle(), field.getField(), messages, field.getScore() + ""};
  }
    i++;
    score = score + field.getScore();
  }
  return data;
  }
```

From above example `field.getTitle(), field.getField()` are of String type And if I want the data in StringBuilder and needs to convert it into string but if I tried to do it by `return data.toString` then it is giving error.
Please Help me.

Comment: Please share both your attempt and the error message as part of your question.

Comment: Also note that `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` are two (similar but) different classes in Java.

Comment: Sorry
Actually I want the data variable in StringBuilder not in STringBuffer.
And if I convert the data to string then on {field.getTitle(), field.getField(), messages, field.getScore() + ""};
  } this line its giving error like incompatibletype . required StringBuilder but it is string

Comment: What do you want the `StringBuilder` to do? Just concatenate all those strings, without any separators? That'll look really bad. --- *"I tried to do it"* Then show us what you tried, so we can help let you know what you did wrong.

Comment: Is the problem solved now? If not what is the format of the output you expect?

Answer (score 18):

To create a StringBuilder from a String simply:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("MyString");
String s = sb.toString();
```

But as was said StringBuilder and StringBuffer are different.  Take a look here for more information on StringBuilder and StringBuffer

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

[Difference between StringBuilder and StringBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/difference-between-stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer)

Answer (score 8):

Convert String to StringBuilder

```
String someText = "something...";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(someText);
```

Comment: flawless answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "rahul";
System.out.println(str.getClass().getName());   
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(str); // way 1
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(); // way 2
sb2.append(str);
System.out.println(sb1.getClass().getName());
System.out.println(sb2.getClass().getName());
```

I hope the code above explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

**StringBuilder** has a constructor that accepts string

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder(java.lang.String)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("my string");
```