# How to trim strings in java without creating a new object?

Tags: java, string, trim

I have a large text file(about 20 million lines) which has lines in the following format :

```
<string1>, <string2>
```

Now those strings may have trailing or leading whitespaces which I want to remove on reading the file.

I am currently using `trim()` for this purpose but since String in Java is immutable, `trim()` is creating a new object per trim operation. 
This is leading to too much wastage of memory.

How can I do it better?

Comment: Please show how you are reading the file and then splitting the strings.

Comment: You do realize that any unused Strings are collected, so there's no real *waste* of memory, just new created objects (which are efficiently collected by the GC).

Comment: I am not quite sure but I think using [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) could solve the problem

Comment: Show the code that you are using to read in the file; with almost complete certainty, trim() will turn out not to be the main memory bottleneck.

Comment: Split your String with comma separator and then , Append each String using StringBuilder .So String not created each time as you said .

Comment: I looked at the logs and full garbage collection was happening frequently..which lead to the application not running at all.. Also, it is a singleton object pattern which is being used.That's why I wanted to narrow down the probable reasons for too much memory being used.

Answer (score 2):

I would be surprised if the immutable `String` class is causing problems; the JVM is very efficient and the result of many years of engineering work.

That said, Java does provide a mutable class for manipulating strings called `StringBuilder`. You can read the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

If you are working across threads, [consider using `StringBuffer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/difference-between-stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer).

Answer (score 0):

You can read your string as a stream of characters, and record the start and end position of each token you want to parse.

This still creates an object per token, but if your tokens are relatively long, the two `int` fields your object will contain are much smaller than the corresponding string would be.

But before you embark on that journey, you should probably just make sure you don't keep your trimmed strings for more time than it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `String` containing `<string1>, <string2>`, and you just want to split it without maybe trimming the parts:

```
String trimmedBetween(String str, int start, int end) {
  while (start < end && Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(start)) {
    ++start;
  }

  while (start < end && Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(end - 1)) {
    --end;
  }

  return str.substring(start, end);
}
```

(Note this is basically how [`String.trim()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java/#2855) is implemented, just with `start` and `end` instead of `0` and `length`)

Then call like:

```
int commaPos = str.indexOf(',');
String firstString = trimmedBetween(str, 0, commaPos);
String secondString = trimmedBetween(str, commaPos + 1, str.length());
```

Comment: I do want to trim the parts i.e. the individual strings.

Comment: Why would I ever want to use this trim instead of the default one? The goal was to avoid memory waste, but you use the same extra memory (= you return a new string) as the built-in `trim()`

Comment: Because `String.trim()` only trims from the beginning and end of the string. To use that you have to split the string (creates an array, and two strings), then trim them (up to two more strings). This approach creates exactly two Strings, instead of 4 Strings and an array.

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, Strings are immutable. So the solution is to not use String, but rather something that is mutable. `StringBuffer` is a suitable class.

However, StringBuffer does not include a trim method, so you can use something like:

```
void trim(StringBuffer sb) {
    int start = 0;
    while (sb.length() > start && Character.isWhitespace(sb.charAt(0))) {
        start++;
    }
    sb.delete(0, start - 1);

    int end = 0;
    while (sb.length() > end && Character.isWhitespace(sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1))) {
        end++;
    }
    sb.delete(sb.length() - end, sb.length() - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid `String` then you have to handle it yourself using `char` and `StringBuilder`, like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("<testfile>"), "UTF-8");

        char[] buffer = new char[32768];
        int read = -1;
        int index;
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
            content.append(buffer, 0, read);
            index = 0;
            while (index > -1) {
                index = content.indexOf("\n");
                if (index > -1) {
                    char[] temp = new char[index];
                    content.getChars(0, index, temp, 0);
                    handleLine(temp);
                    content.replace(0, index + 1, "");
                }
            }
        }

        in.close();
    }

    private static void handleLine(char[] line) {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder().append(line);
        int start = 0;
        int end = content.length();
        if (end > 0) {
            char ch = content.charAt(0);
            while (Character.isWhitespace(content.charAt(start))) {
                start++;
                if (end <= start) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (start < end) {
                while (Character.isWhitespace(content.charAt(end - 1))) {
                    end--;
                    if (end <= start) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("***" + content.subSequence(start, end) + "***");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We could handle by Regex.

```
   {
    String str = "abcd, efgh";
    String [] result = str.split("(,\\s)|,");
    Arrays.asList(result).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you can directly write the result data to a new file.

```
String originStr = "   xxxxyyyy";
for (int i = 0; i < originStr.length(); i++) {
    if (' ' == originStr.charAt(i)) {
        continue;
    }
    NewFileOutPutStream.write(originStr.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: if u using m-thread model, you can separated your file, let them to be few chunk file for logical, and then above method is also worked well.

Comment: Writing a single char at a time will take forever. You need to buffer it.