# Convert string to reverse int array

Tags: java, arrays, string

**I want to optimize this solution (idiomatically).**

I have a string containing only integer values. I want to convert this string into reverse int array. The output should be an integer array

Here is my solution:

```
private static int[] stringToReversedIntArray(String num) {
    int[] a = new int[num.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
        a[i] = Integer.parseInt(num.substring(i, i + 1));
    }
    a = reverse(a);
    return a;
}

/*
 * Reverses an int array
 */
private static int[] reverse(int[] myArray) {
    int[] reversed = new int[myArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        reversed[i] = myArray[myArray.length - (i + 1)];
    }
    return reversed;
}

Input: "1256346258"
Output: {8,5,2,6,4,3,6,5,2,1}
```

Please suggest how to do same.

Comment: What 'standard library method calls' have you tried? Have you done any research to see what is available?

Comment: reverse at the same time you *decode* the original string : `a[num.length()-i-1] = num.charAt(i)-'0';`

Comment: This question appears to have an already working solution by OP. It may be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One-liner:

```
return IntStream
    .range(0, num.length())
    .map(i -> Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(num.length() - i - 1)))
    .toArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var input = "1256346258";
var result = Arrays
        .stream(new StringBuffer(input).reverse().toString().split(""))
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: StringBuffer → StringBuilder

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov StringBuilder can be replaced by StringBuffer where synchronization is not required, like discussed 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/difference-between-stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer)

Comment: It can be but it shouldn't

Answer (score 2):

Since you are extracting one character at a time, using `charAt` instead of `substring` makes more sense.

And since you are converting a single character to an `int`, `Character.getNumericValue()` makes more sense then `parseInt`.

Hence I'd change

```
a[i] = Integer.parseInt(num.substring(i, i + 1));
```

to

```
a[i] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i));
```

You can also simplify the reverse part as follows if you don't mind using an `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`:

```
private static Integer[] stringToReversedIntArray(String num) {
    Integer[] a = new Integer[num.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
        a[i] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i));
    }
    Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(a));
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Small note about `getNumericValue`. It will output weird numeric values if you pass alphabet characters, while `parseInt()` is a bit safer and throws a `NumberFormatException`. Of course each is convenient in its own way.

Comment: @jbx well, the OP did say `string containing only integer values`

Comment: Yes of course, the solution is perfectly valid. Just included the note for the future reader who would like to use this option. Because it is easy to miss this subtle difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use streams you can do it with something like this:

```
Deque<String> deque = num.chars()
   .map(c -> Character.toString((char) c))
   .map(Integer::parseInt)
   .collect(Collector.of(
        ArrayDeque::new,
        (stack, i) -> stack.addFirst(i),
        (s1, s2) -> { s2.addAll(s1); return s2; })); //this combiner won't really be called unless the stream was parallel

Integer[] reversed = deque.toArray(new Integer[deque.size()]);
```

This loops through the list just once. The `Deque` can work as a stack, Last In First Out, so each `addFirst()` will automatically reverse the order since it adds each item to the front not the back of the list. You can convert it to an array afterwards, or use the `Deque` as is, which is a normal `Collection` and implements `Iterable`.

As other answers mentioned, you could also simplify it a bit like this, if you are 100% sure you have only digits, because with the simplified version you won't get a `NumberFormatException`.

```
Deque<String> deque = num.chars()
   .map(c -> Character.getNumericValue((char) c))
   .collect(Collector.of(
        ArrayDeque::new,
        (stack, i) -> stack.addFirst(i),
        (s1, s2) -> { s2.addAll(s1); return s2; }));

Integer[] reversed = deque.toArray(new Integer[deque.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop 2 times, you can use StringBuilder to reverse a String, and then loop over it to store the result in your int array:

```
  private static int[] stringToReversedIntArray(String num) {
    num = new StringBuilder(num).reverse().toString();
    int[] result = new int[num.length()]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
      result[i] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i)); 
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Other options would either be to just reverse your for loop and have it count backwards:

```
for(int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  ...
}
```

Or use the Stream API in recent versions of Java, as has already been mentioned above in a nice example.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "123456";
// Reverse String
str = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
String strArr[] = str.split("(?!^)");
// Convert to Int Array
int[] intarray = java.util.Arrays.stream(strings).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Erans solution is fine to me, but i dont like the for loop and i prefer if possible the stream api

```
String testString = "1256346258";
IntStream intStream = testString.chars();       
List<Integer> x = intStream.boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.reverse(x);
int[] array = x.stream().mapToInt(i -> Character.getNumericValue(i)).toArray();
System.out.println("x: " + Arrays.toString(array));
```

just wrap it with a nice method...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution with a single for loop. You can "reverse" the digits at the same time you extract the numeric values, just by playing a bit with the indexes:

```
private static int[] stringToReversedIntArray(String num) {
    int len = num.length();
    int[] a = new int[len];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        a[i] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(len - i - 1));
    }
    return a;
}
```