# How does the word "buffer" indicate synchronization in StringBuffer

Tags: java

Is the word "buffer" indicating synchronization in `StringBuffer`?
if I assume yes, how is it done?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/difference-between-stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because remembering names is not a programming problem. It is a fun question, but still off topic I believe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word "Buffer" is not related to the synchronization. It is just a convenient buffer to collect and manipulate a string.

StringBuilder was invented later to provide better performance. Again, the word "Builder" is not related to the synchronization.